# Extracting raw data from template for use in CUDA

Tags: c++, templates, opencv, cuda

The following code is a snippet from the PCL (point cloud) library. It calculates the integral sum of an image.

```
template <class DataType, unsigned Dimension> class IntegralImage2D
{
    public:
        static const unsigned dim_fst = Dimension;
        typedef cv::Vec<typename TypeTraits<DataType>::IntegralType, dim_fst> FirstType;
        std::vector<FirstType>  img_fst;

        //.... lots of methods missing here that actually calculate the integral sum

        /** \brief Compute the first order sum within a given rectangle
          * \param[in] start_x x position of rectangle
          * \param[in] start_y y position of rectangle
          * \param[in] width width of rectangle
          * \param[in] height height of rectangle
          */
        inline FirstType getFirstOrderSum(unsigned start_x, unsigned start_y, unsigned width, unsigned height) const
        {
            const unsigned upper_left_idx  = start_y * (wdt + 1) + start_x;
            const unsigned upper_right_idx = upper_left_idx + width;
            const unsigned lower_left_idx  =(start_y + height) * (wdt + 1) + start_x;
            const unsigned lower_right_idx = lower_left_idx + width;

            return(img_fst[lower_right_idx] + img_fst[upper_left_idx] - img_fst[upper_right_idx] - img_fst[lower_left_idx]);
        }
```

Currently the results are obtained using the following code:

```
IntegralImage2D<float,3> iim_xyz;

IntegralImage2D<float, 3>::FirstType  fo_elements;
IntegralImage2D<float, 3>::SecondType so_elements;
fo_elements = iim_xyz.getFirstOrderSum(pos_x - rec_wdt_2, pos_y - rec_hgt_2, rec_wdt, rec_hgt);
so_elements = iim_xyz.getSecondOrderSum(pos_x - rec_wdt_2, pos_y - rec_hgt_2, rec_wdt, rec_hgt);
```

However I'm trying to parallelise the code (write getFirstOrderSum as a CUDA device function). Since CUDA doesn't recognise these FirstType and SecondType  objects (or any opencv objects for that matter) I'm struggling (I'm new to C++) to extract the raw data from the template.

**If possible I would like to cast the img_fst object to some kind of vector or array that I can allocate on the cuda kernel.**

it seems img_fst is of type `std::vector<cv::Matx<double,3,1>`

Comment: Perhaps not directly related to your question, but the [npp library](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/index.html#abstract) provides methods to compute integral images.

Comment: It seems you are looking for `Mat::ptr`.

Comment: @Jarod42: can you elaborate? That's for mat and not for vec right?

Comment: As I read, `Vec` is an alias for `Mat`, and `Mat` has `ptr` which seems to be the equivalent of `std::vector::data()` which returns pointer to contiguous memory containing data.

Comment: yes but in this case it is an allias for Matx which doesn't provide such a pointer sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out you can pass the raw data as you would using a normal vector.

```
void computation(ps::IntegralImage2D<float, 3> iim_xyz){
    cv::Vec<double, 3>* d_img_fst = 0;
    cudaErrorCheck(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_img_fst, sizeof(cv::Vec<double, 3>)*(iim_xyz.img_fst.size())));
    cudaErrorCheck(cudaMemcpy(d_img_fst, &iim_xyz.img_fst[0], sizeof(cv::Vec<double, 3>)*(iim_xyz.img_fst.size()), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
//..
}

__device__ double* getFirstOrderSum(unsigned start_x, unsigned start_y, unsigned width, unsigned height, int wdt, cv::Vec<double, 3>* img_fst)
{
    const unsigned upper_left_idx = start_y * (wdt + 1) + start_x;
    const unsigned upper_right_idx = upper_left_idx + width;
    const unsigned lower_left_idx = (start_y + height) * (wdt + 1) + start_x;
    const unsigned lower_right_idx = lower_left_idx + width;

    double* result = new double[3];
    result[0] = img_fst[lower_right_idx].val[0] + img_fst[upper_left_idx].val[0] - img_fst[upper_right_idx].val[0] - img_fst[lower_left_idx].val[0];
    result[1] = img_fst[lower_right_idx].val[1] + img_fst[upper_left_idx].val[1] - img_fst[upper_right_idx].val[1] - img_fst[lower_left_idx].val[1];
    result[2] = img_fst[lower_right_idx].val[2] + img_fst[upper_left_idx].val[2] - img_fst[upper_right_idx].val[2] - img_fst[lower_left_idx].val[2];

    return result; //i have to delete this pointer otherwise I will create memory leak
}
```